# Rstudio packages not updating

Tags: r, package

I have had the latest version of R and the latest version of Rstudio for at least a few weeks and every time I check for package updates, it's 'all packages are up to date'.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `update.packages(ask = FALSE)` in the Console and got all the updates. Thereafter, the Rstudio `Update` button started working again.